# How to create a "naval Battle" style table with radio buttons in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How to create a "naval Battle" style table with radio buttons where I send the value of the radio button ( column ) and the value of the Line (line).

For example:

```
alfa beta omega

o     x     x    A
x     o     x    B
x     o     x    C
```

Being "o" the selected ones, I want to receive ALFA and A, BETA and B and BETA and  C in the backing bean, **being single selection in each row, not column.**
The thing is the number of columns is dynamic according to the number of rows retrieved from the DB.

Here's what I managed to do unti now. The columns are Units and the lines are Lines

```
<h:dataTable value="#{unidadeController.listLines}" var="itemList">

                            <h:column>
                                <c:forEach var="i" begin="0"
                                    end="#{bean.listUnits.size()-1}">

                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{bean.getUnitName(i)}" />
                                        <p:spacer width="50" height="0" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                </c:forEach>
                                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.unit}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listUnits}"
                                        var="c" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
                                </h:selectOneRadio>
                            </h:column>

                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{labelController.name}" />
                                    <br />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{itemList.name}" />
                                <br />
                            </h:column>

                        </h:dataTable>
```

Bean:

```
private Unit unit = new Unit();

private List<Unit> units = new ArrayList<Unit>();

 public List<Unit> getListUnits()
    {
        if (this.units.isEmpty())
        {
            try
            {
                this.units= Cache.getInstance().getUnits();
            }
            catch (final WplexEOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return this.units;
    }

public List<Line> getListLines()
{
    try
    {
        return Cache.getInstance().getLines();
    }
    catch (final WplexEOException e)
    {
        e.exibeErroNaPagina();
    }
    return new ArrayList<Line>();
}

public String getUnitName(final int index)
    {
        return this.units.get(index).getName();
    }
```

[image: zxcvzxcv]

alfa, beta, omega are the units. a,b,c are the lines.

Nome means name in Portuguese, as in name of the line.

Its rendereing how I want to, but radio isn't passing its value to the bean and I need to send the line index or value also. How can I fix/improve this?

**Edit:**
I changed table to use a map, but the when I access the map it's empty.

```
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.listLines}" var="itemList">

                        <h:column>
                            <c:forEach var="itemForEach" items="#{bean.listUnits}" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{itemForEach.getName()}" />
                                    <p:spacer width="50" height="0" />
                                </f:facet>
                            </c:forEach>
                            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.mapLines[itemList]}" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listaUnits}"
                                    var="c" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{c.id}" />
                            </h:selectOneRadio>
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{labelController.name}" />
                                <br />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{itemList.name}" />
                            <br />
                        </h:column>

                    </h:dataTable>
```

bean:

```
private Map<Line, Integer> mapLines = new HashMap<Line, Integer>();
```

Line class: ( In portuguese, sorry )

Linha = line

Nome = name

Unidade = unit

```
   /*
 * $Id: javadoctemplates.xml,v 1.2 2007/05/29 19:28:02 mauro Exp $
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2004-2007 Wplex Software Ltda. All rights reserved.
 */

package com.wplexeo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import com.wplexeo.exception.WplexEOException;

/**
 * Linha da programação
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Entity(name = "linha")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "native")
public class Linha extends Entidade implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String nome; //name

    @ManyToOne
    private Unidade unidade;

    /**
     * @param idDaBusca
     * @return Evento
     * @throws WplexEOException
     */
    public static Linha buscaPorId(final Long idDaBusca) throws WplexEOException
    {
        return (Linha) Entidade.buscaPorId(Linha.class, idDaBusca);
    }

    /**
     * @return Evento
     * @throws WplexEOException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<Linha> lista() throws WplexEOException
    {
        return (List<Linha>) Entidade.lista(Linha.class);
    }

    /**
     * @throws WplexEOException
     */
    public static void removeTodos() throws WplexEOException
    {
        Entidade.removeTodos(Linha.class);
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(final String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + (this.nome == null ? 0 : this.nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (this.unidade == null ? 0 : this.unidade.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!super.equals(obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        final Linha other = (Linha) obj;
        if (this.nome == null)
        {
            if (other.nome != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!this.nome.equals(other.nome))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.unidade == null)
        {
            if (other.unidade != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!this.unidade.equals(other.unidade))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing the method bean.getUnitName(int i) in your above example.

Comment: updated to show the method

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake for not explaining this. Single selection for each row. So in my example you could select three omegas: omega a, omega b, omega c.

Comment: Ah lol... ok ignore my answer it is far off and I don't have time to redo it. I thought you only wanted to let 1 selection in the whole grid. one choice per row is pretty straight forward really I'm sure someone will be able to answer this. otherwise i'll change my answer end of day

Comment: @Joeblade don't delete it, it can be helpfull. Let me just play with your idea a little

Comment: @BalusC I'll try the solution proposed there, and see if solves my problem. Just a min.

Comment: My solution uses a single variable across all rows, you'd have to adjust it to have a variable per row. which is pretty standard, I think you can bind a bean property. I'll leave it till tonight, downvote if it's not correct / appropriate/ doesn't work and i'll rmeove it again :)   just keep in mind the first comment still stands. no need to use list indexes if you can iterate over beans.

Comment: @BalusC I used a map like in the link you passed but it's not passing the values to the bean. I edited the question to show you.

Comment: I did after you told me but still no luck (edited my post again ). Should I post another question to SO since my original doubt has been solved and this is a new one?

Comment: @BalusC I was checking the map inside a method I was calling through a commandlink, but I was using immediate="true". So I didn't removed the tag, but started using <f:ajax> and that solved the problem. I don't know if the values are being passed correctly, but the map is no empty anymore. This kind of thing pisses me off.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I am fairly sure you can replace this

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="#{bean.listUnits.size()-1}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.getUnitName(i)}" />
        <p:spacer width="50" height="0" />
    </f:facet>
</c:forEach>
```

With (assuming the bean has a getName() method)

```
<c:forEach var="beanListUnit" items="#{bean.listUnits">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{beanListUnit.getName()}" />
        <p:spacer width="50" height="0" />
    </f:facet>
</c:forEach>
```

Secondly I would not use Cache.getInstance and reusing the private List units for different rows, but leaving it unchanged for now.

Then on to how to detect row + column, how I used to do this is (this may be outdated, but :D it's the way I figured it out) is to do something like:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{unidadeController.listLines}" var="itemList">
    <h:column>
        <c:forEach var="currentBean" items="#{bean.listUnits}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bean.getUnitName(i)}" />
                <p:spacer width="50" height="0" />
            </f:facet>
        </c:forEach>
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.unit}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.radioButtonChange}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.listUnits}" var="c" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{bean.id}:#{c.id}" />
        </h:selectOneRadio>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{labelController.name}" /><br />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{itemList.name}" /><br />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And expand your bean with: (see [mkyong's example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-valuechangelistener-example/))

```
public void radioButtonChange(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    // value was changed
    String newValue = e.getNewValue().toString(); // assert not null etc
    String[] rowCol = newValue.split(":"); // assert rowCol.length == 2
    String rowId = rowCol[0];
    String colId = rowCol[1];
    // do what you wanted to do, sink a battleship
}
```

I have descended into pseudocode a little, with

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.listUnits}" var="c" itemLabel="" itemValue="#{bean.id}:#{c.id}" />
```

But basically, in the itemValue I would encode row and column (assuming c.id doesn't already contain the information for both) and onItemChange I would split this information again so you can act on it.

if id already contains this info (unique for each row/column then you can ignore this part)